# Making XFCE GUI programs

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, gui

I would like to make an application that keeps the icons on the desktop grouped within certain application defined "fences" on linux. I have a general idea of how to interact with the linux operating system by making system() calls, however I dont know how to interact with the GUI component on top of linux.

I am running Xubuntu, which I know use XFCE, and from the wikipedia page I know there exist some Xfce libraries but I havent been able to find any examples. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction

Comment: Your question maybe a bit non-specific for Ask Ubuntu. I suggest you [get in touch](https://www.xfce.org/getinvolved) with the XFCE developers directly.

Comment: You could always pick a simple program you like, and `sudo apt-get source <package>` to download the source for the program you'd like to use as your example. *this is simplified, and you may need to add packages to build/compile source I'm skipping*

Comment: Desktop window would be managed by whatever file manager is default for XFCE. They do have certain APIs, most of them are in C, but I cannot say if there's API specific to file manager or desktop window.  The application idea you have is interesting, though I'm not sure how that could be implemented - desktop windows aren't very extensible. Consider writing that as separate windowed application.